# nil can't be coerced into Float on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this error:

```
app/views/carts/show.html.erb:6 raised:

nil can't be coerced into Float
```

Model:

```
class CartItem
  attr_reader :product_id, :quantity

  def  initialize (product_id, quantity= 1)
    @product_id = product_id
    @quantity = quantity
  end

  def increment
    @quantity = @quantity + 1
  end

  def product
    Product.find product_id
  end

  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% @cart.items.each do |item|%>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
      <td><%= item.product.name %></td>
      <td><%= item.total_price %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :initialize_cart

  def add
    @cart.add_item params[:id]
    session['cart'] = @cart.serialize
    product = Product.find params[:id]
    redirect_to :back, notice:  "Added #{product.name} to cart."
  end

  def show; end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using pry to inspect the value of total_price on page load or when the method is invoked? Seems to be mil at the moment so it's not being set correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
def total_price
    product.price * quantity
end
```

you should have

```
def total_price
    product.price * @quantity
end
```

because `@quantity` is a instance variable.